# syncing a GTK iterTree with a list

Tags: c#, list, mono, treeview, gtk

i have the following problem,
i created a tree model with the folowing arguments :

```
    this.Mods = SDVMMR.ModListManagment.LoadList(ModStore);

    // Createing  columns
    Gtk.TreeViewColumn CBColumn = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn();
    CBColumn.Title = "Active";

    Gtk.CellRendererText CBCell = new Gtk.CellRendererText();
    CBColumn.PackStart(CBCell, true);

    Gtk.TreeViewColumn NameColumn = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn();
    NameColumn.Title = "Name";

    Gtk.CellRendererText ModsNameCell = new Gtk.CellRendererText();
    NameColumn.PackStart(ModsNameCell, true);

    Gtk.TreeViewColumn AuthorColumn = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn();
    AuthorColumn.Title = "Author";

    Gtk.CellRendererText AuthorCell = new Gtk.CellRendererText();
    AuthorColumn.PackStart(AuthorCell, true);

    Gtk.TreeViewColumn VersionColumn = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn();
    VersionColumn.Title = "Version";

    Gtk.CellRendererText VersionCell = new Gtk.CellRendererText();
    VersionColumn.PackStart(VersionCell, true);

    // Add the columns to the TreeView
    activeMods.AppendColumn(CBColumn);
    activeMods.AppendColumn(NameColumn);
    activeMods.AppendColumn(AuthorColumn);
    activeMods.AppendColumn(VersionColumn);

    NameColumn.AddAttribute(ModsNameCell, "text", 1);
    AuthorColumn.AddAttribute(AuthorCell, "text", 2);
    VersionColumn.AddAttribute(VersionCell, "text",3);

    // the column checkbox is created
    Gtk.CellRendererToggle valueCb = new CellRendererToggle();
    CBColumn.PackStart(valueCb, true);




    activeMods.Model = ModStore;
```

the in the code used mods consists of an internal definition:
internal List Mods = new List();

Fore refrence here the used ModInfo:

```
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string UniqueID { get; set; }
    public string MinimumApiVersion { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string EntryDll { get; set;}
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsXnb { get; set; }
    public string OrgXnbPath { get; set; }
```

the function i currently use looks like:

```
        internal static void addToTree(ModInfo Mod, ListStore ModStore)
    {

        /*Gtk.TreeIter iter = ModStore.AppendValues(Mod.Name);
        ModStore.AppendValues(iter, "Author", Mod.Author);
        ModStore.AppendValues(iter, "Version", Mod.Version);
        ModStore.AppendValues(iter, "Description", Mod.Description);
        ModStore.AppendValues(iter, "Is Active", Mod.IsActive.ToString());*/

    ModStore.AppendValues(Mod.IsActive.ToString(),Mod.Name,Mod.Author,Mod.Version);


    }
```

but this one doesnt accepts the list entries. So is there a way for it to also accept the in memory list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model creation seems wrong. You probably don't won't to have a List as the type of the model items. Probably you want the type the list contains:

`... new Gtk.TreeStore(typeof(SDVMMR.ModInfo));`.

Assuming that this class SDVMMR.ModInfo is the class with the properties you have indicated, then to add the items in your list and populate the model, you should do something like:

```
foreach (ModInfo Mod in List<SDVMMR.ModInfo>) {
   activeMods.AppendValues (Mod);
}
```

You also need to customize the cell data functions in order for the treeview to know where to get the data from.

```
private void RenderNameCell (Gtk.TreeViewColumn column, Gtk.CellRenderer cell, Gtk.TreeModel model, Gtk.TreeIter iter)
{
    SVDMMR.ModInfo modinfo = (SVDMMR.ModInfo) model.GetValue (iter, 0);
    (cell as Gtk.CellRendererText).Text = modinfo.name;
}

private void RenderValueCell (Gtk.TreeViewColumn column, Gtk.CellRenderer cell, Gtk.TreeModel model, Gtk.TreeIter iter)
{
    // You didn't say what the value is so lets use UniqueID

    SVDMMR.ModInfo modinfo = (SVDMMR.ModInfo) model.GetValue (iter, 0);
    (cell as Gtk.CellRendererText).Text = modinfo.UniqueID;
}
```

These methods must be setup on the cell renderers:

```
NameColumn.SetCellDataFunc (ModsNameCell, new Gtk.TreeCellDataFunc (RenderNameCell));
ValueColumn.SetCellDataFunc (ModValueCell, new Gtk.TreeCellDataFunc (RenderValueCell));
```

Your code is incomplete and missing a few hints so the answer may also be incomplete.

Comment: i got it work somewhat myself but need a second function to parse the loaded list into the treeview (liststore) on launch of the application.

Comment: sadly wont be accepted by the compile due "Error CS0230: Type and identifier are both required in a foreach statement (CS0230) (SDVMMR)"

Comment: @yuuki can you describe better what is that SDVMMR and SDVMMR.ModInfo?

Comment: i got it fixed by changing 
foreach (modinfo in List<SDVMMR.ModInfo>) {
   activeMods.AppendValues (modinfo);
}

to

foreach (ModInfo Mod in List<SDVMMR.ModInfo>) {
   activeMods.AppendValues (Mod);
}

Comment: ok, i'll fix the answer. I was a bit confused with the classes there. Not much info on that. Thanks

Comment: Just to try and clarify a bit.
ModInfo is basicly a Json Container Dummy for reading the data out of Json when starting the programm (while the programm is running the infos are kept in memory. once it closes it gets saved in to a json which is loaded in the list again when the programm is startet again.)